# Webpack ignore code splitting when target node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I've got a node app that uses react-router to render React views server-side. My issue is that I'm using `require.ensure` to do code splitting on the client-side but don't want to have code splitting when I compile my server-side code. Here is my webpack config:

```
{
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '../server/app.js'),
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'server.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: 'handlebars-loader', include: /client/ }
    ]
  },
  externals: nodeModules
}
```

When I run it, I get server.js, 1.server.js, 2.server.js, etc. I'd rather just have a single server.js file.

At the top of each route file I have:

```
if (typeof require.ensure !== 'function') require.ensure = (d, c) => c(require);
```

Which works when I use `require('babel/register')` in development, but I'd rather have a compiled file for production.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've addressed this with conditionals around the require. If it's a browser build, require.ensure, if it's a server build, just require. I use the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) to define 'constant' variables for the environment for each build, so it would look something like

```
if (BUILD_BROWSER) {
  require.ensure('foo.js', function() { ... });
} else {
  require('foo.js');
  ...
}
```

Webpack's static analysis is only smart enough to understand boolean values, so doing something like `if (BUILD_TARGET === 'browser')` won't work; the parser won't follow the logic and will process both requires.

If you're using the Uglify plugin, that will strip out the unneeded conditional logic so you don't bloat your production build.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Comment: but then you have the problem with React where the checksums don't matchup between the server-side-rendered HTML and the HTML generated on the client, thereby losing many of the of "benefits" of server side rendering. I.e. the server and the client each render different HTML. In addition, I'm not even sure how on the client to conditionally load from a different js bundle embedded in the DOM (which you only render for the given route) without now triggering your main bundle to include the same files. It seems it could only work by creating entry points for each route, rather than `ensure`.