# How to structure a Vue 2.0 app for server-rendered lazy routes?

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, isomorphic-javascript, vue-router

I attempted to modify [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) to support lazy-loaded routes using Webpack's [code-splitting feature](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) as per instructions found at these links:

- https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html
- http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Async-Components

However, I ran into some issues. When I loaded the app in the browser, all suggested variations of syntax triggered `Module not found` errors on the server-side when attempting to load in the server-side chunks.

Given this wrapper around the code-split points in `router.js`...

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

// INSERT CODE-SPLIT POINT SYNTAXES HERE (they are below)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: Home
  }, {
    path: '/foo',
    component: Foo
  }]
})
```

All of these variations of syntax threw the `Module not found` error:

**Variation 1:**

```
const Home = () => System.import('./views/Home.vue')
const Foo = () => System.import('./views/Foo.vue')
```

**Variation 2:**

```
const Home = (resolve) => require(['./views/Home.vue'], resolve)
const Foo = (resolve) => require(['./views/Foo.vue'], resolve)
```

**Variation 3:**

```
const Home = (resolve) => {
  require.ensure(['./views/Home.vue'], () => {
    resolve(require('./views/Home.vue'))
  })
}

const Foo = (resolve) => {
  require.ensure(['./views/Foo.vue'], () => {
    resolve(require('./views/Foo.vue'))
  })
}
```

The error message was always along the lines of:
*(note: this error is adapted from a small reproduction I made of the issue, **not** from the hackernews example)*

```
Error: Cannot find module './0.server.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at Function.requireEnsure [as e] (__vue_ssr_bundle__:42:25)
  at Home (__vue_ssr_bundle__:152:30)
  at /Users/razorbeard/projects/vue-2-ssr/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js:1421:19
  at iterator (/Users/razorbeard/projects/vue-2-ssr/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js:1277:5)
  at step (/Users/razorbeard/projects/vue-2-ssr/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js:1213:9)
  at step (/Users/razorbeard/projects/vue-2-ssr/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js:1217:9)
```

I tried adapting my code to use the suggestions offered at [Server-side react with webpack 2 System.import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121442/server-side-react-with-webpack-2-system-import), but those did not work either.

I read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372503/webpack-ignore-code-splitting-when-target-node?rq=1) that described configuring a build-time global variable using Webpack's `DefinePlugin` that allowed me to inspect whether the code was running on the server or on the client - this allows me to code-split on the client, but just bundle everything in on the server.

In the server webpack config:

```
{
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BROWSER_BUILD: false
    })
  ]
  ...
}
```

In the client webpack config:

```
{
 ...
 plugins: [
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     BROWSER_BUILD: true
   })
 ]
 ...
}
```

Then, in the same wrapper-snippet as above for the `router.js` file, I used this variation of syntax:

```
const Home = BROWSER_BUILD ? () => System.import('./views/Home.vue') : require('./views/Home.vue')
const Foo = BROWSER_BUILD ? () => System.import('./views/Foo.vue') : require('./views/Foo.vue')
```

This made rendering work - partially. Navigating directly to the app in the browser (and respective routes) server-rendered the correct UI. Clicking around, `vue-router`'s client-side logic took me to the right UI. Everything seemed hunky-dory - until I opened DevTools:

[image: error in devtools about mismatched DOM and VNode tree]

The same issue also occurs if a module is loaded lazily as a subcomponent of a route:

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
    <heading></heading>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  const Heading = BROWSER_BUILD ? () => System.import('./Heading.vue') : require('./Heading.vue')
  export default {
    components: {
      Heading
    }
  }
</script>
```

I tried asking for some help in the official Vue forum, but came up empty: http://forum.vuejs.org/t/2-0-help-needed-with-server-rendered-lazy-routes/906

Thinking this might be a bug with `vue-router`, I opened an issue there: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/820

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a solution.

So, I put together a small repo that reproduces the issue: https://github.com/declandewet/vue2-ssr-lazy-error

I have a hunch that the actual problem might be coming from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-server-renderer.

I'm really stuck on this and am used to how easy it is to do in react - and would really appreciate any help/tips/direction towards a solution!

Here is the webpack config from the reproduction repo for convenience:

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import validate from 'webpack2-validator'
import { dependencies } from './package.json'

let babelConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc'))

/* turn off modules in es2015 preset to enable tree-shaking
   (this is on in babelrc because setting it otherwise causes issues with
   this config file) */
babelConfig.presets = babelConfig.presets.map(
  (preset) => preset === 'es2015' ? ['es2015', { modules: false }] : preset
)

const babelOpts = {
  ...babelConfig,
  babelrc: false,
  cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache'
}

const SHARED_CONFIG = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue'
    }, {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: 'node_modules',
      query: babelOpts
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, './src'),
      'node_modules'
    ]
  }
}

const SERVER_CONFIG = validate({
  ...SHARED_CONFIG,
  target: 'node',
  entry: {
    server: './src/server.js',
    renderer: './src/renderer.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].server.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BROWSER_BUILD: false,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: 'require("source-map-support").install();',
      raw: true,
      entryOnly: false
    })
  ],
  externals: Object.keys(dependencies)
})

const CLIENT_CONFIG = validate({
  ...SHARED_CONFIG,
  entry: {
    app: './src/client.js',
    vendor: ['vue']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist/assets'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BROWSER_BUILD: true,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filename: 'vendor.js'
    })
  ]
})

export default [SERVER_CONFIG, CLIENT_CONFIG]
```

**EDIT:** Noticing that in React, we use `match` on the client to get the right route config for the current view, I decided to inspect what components were getting matched using `app.$router.getMatchedComponents()` and found something interesting:

**Server Entry:**

```
import app from './app'

export default (context) => {
  // using app.$router instead of importing router itself works
  // (not sure why the hacker-news example imports the router module instead...)
  app.$router.push(context.url)
  const components = app.$router.getMatchedComponents()
  console.log('server-side', components)
  return Promise.all(components.map((component) => component))
    .then(() => app)
}
```

When navigating to the home page, this logs to the terminal:

```
server-side [ { __file: '/Users/razorbeard/projects/vue-2-ssr/src/views/Home.vue',
    render: [Function],
    staticRenderFns: [ [Function] ] } ]
```

**Client Entry:**

```
import app from './app'

const components = app.$router.getMatchedComponents()

console.log('client-side', components)

// kickoff client-side hydration
Promise.all(components.map((component) => Promise.resolve(component)))
  .then(() => app.$mount('#app'))
```

When navigating to the home page, this logs to the devtools console:

```
client-side []
```

As you can see, no components are getting matched on the client side.

Comment: I encourage you to check the [vue-example](https://github.com/xpepermint/vue-example/) which is based on [vue-cli-template](https://github.com/xpepermint/vue-cli-template).

Comment: @xpepermint At first glance, your example does not seem to implement lazy rendering at all. Am I missing something?

By the way, the solution to my problem was found here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/issues/17#issuecomment-258175320

But its a hack - waiting on a cleaner alternative before updating this question. I hear one is in the works.

Comment: True, I thought that you are also looking for a server-side rendering project example.

Comment: @razorbeard Did you find a solution to this?